# How to correctly maintain database schema in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, database-schema, table-relationships

I have schema like this:

```
create_table "grades", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "cls"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "post_grades", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.integer "grade_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.string "title"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

create_table "user_grades", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "grade_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

In this schema grades, posts and users all are related to each other.

So my first question: Is it correct way of doing this?

Suppose one of user added grade 4 (cls = 4) in his column and another user added same grade. Now I have same value of cls in grade table for two different grade ids.So is there any data redundancy  in this schema?

Comment: Can you describe logic of your tables? Too hard to say something useful without any conceptual understanding

Comment: User have many grades and can post posts in those grades.
Grades can have many posts and a post can only be in one grade .
A grade can have many users.
Is it enough or need to elaborate more?

Comment: Does `Grade` has any specific user like a creator/etc or they are all similar?

Comment: What is `cls`? Yes, your response makes things a bit clear, but still need a bit more info to help you

Comment: Yeah in this User have many roles like Admin, Teacher and Student in which only Admin and Teacher can post posts in grades.

Comment: cls is like different standards in schools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I got your task, you can go with such solution:

1. `grades` -> no references (as it is right now)
2. `user_grades` (conventional way to name this table would be `grades_users`... alphabetical order and both in plural) -> `user_id`, `grade_id` (as it is right now)
3. You don't need `post_grades`. It's redundant
4. `posts` -> `grade_id`, `user_id` (if you need author)

Your `schema.rb` will look smth like:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
end

create_table "grades_users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.integer "grade_id"
  ...
end

create_table "grades", force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
end

create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "user_id", null: false
  t.integer "grade_id", null: false
  ...
end
```

Comment: Suppose one of user added in grade (cls: 4) in his column and another user added same grade. Now I have same value of cls in grade table for two different grade ids.So is this also data redundancy ?

Comment: No, it's not data redundancy, because following such approach you can end up that all duplicate data is redundancy. Do you need `Grade` to be created only with unique `cls` field?

Comment: No..for a particular User ..Grade is created only with unique cls field but of course different user can have same cls field as other User has..

Comment: Then everything is all right. And, please, let's get back to your initial question. Right now it's already a new question. Have my answer helped you? If yes, then please mark it with a tick and up vote for future searches. Lost of thanks in advance.